# Get list of Y's on linspace from X's and Y's arrays in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two arrays - X points and Y points. X array have some spaces (e. g. [0 1 2 6 7 8]), and Y array contains only values for that Xes. I've got that array as a local maxima from wavelet transform. I can plot it with `plot(X,Y)`

Now I want to get Y's on linspace - Y must contain values for any X from 0 to 8. I want to have the same plot `plot(Y)` as the previous `plot(X, Y)`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to perform interpolation

```
xPts = [0 1 2 6 7 8];
yPts = ...

xPlot = 0:1:8;
yPlot = interp1(xPts,yPts,xPlot,'cubic')

plot(xPlot,yPlot)
```

Check [the documentation for interp1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) for the different interpolation schemes.

If there are repeated x-values, you can average the corresponding y-values

```
   xPtsRep = [0 0 1 2 6 7 7 8]
   yPtsRep = ...

   [xPts,~,xIdx] = unique(xPtsRep);
   yPts = accumarray(xIdx,yPtsRep,[],@mean);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want, but I encountered a problem - my Xs vector had some repeated values, and I getting error about `stricktly monotonic increasing` vector. In my case, vector is increasing, but not strictly. What can I do with this?

Comment: @skayred: you can e.g. average the y-values corresponding to the duplicate x-entries.